# LAPACK sgelss usage

Tags: ios, math, lapack

I would like to use the sgelss function from the LAPACK framework to solve an overdetermined system of linear equations.

```
minimize || A*x-b||
```

For this I chose to use the sgelss function from LAPACK, the header file can be found here: [SGELSS](http://www.math.utah.edu/software/lapack/lapack-s/sgelss.html)

My problem is that I seam to use it wrong, since the results don't fit.

An example case, I use these matricies:

```
double a[] =
    {
       25,5,1,
       16,4,1,
        9,3,1,
        4,2,1,
        1,1,1,
    };
double b[] =
     {
       31,21,13,7,3
     }
```

And then I would call:

```
sgelss_(&(5), &(3), &(1), a, (5), b, &(5), 3, -1, &(3), malloc(3000), &(3000), &output);
```

[[ Since sgelss expects most input variables not to be normal variables but pointers I use &(...) here in order to skip instantiating variables and then referencing their memory location for sake of readability here! ]]

I would expect that afterwards b would be [1,1,1,XXXXX] since my inputs a and b were set up this way. Unfortunately this is not the case.

I have also tried rotating a (switching rows and columns), without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of problems in the code that you posted; I assume that it’s abstracted from what you’re really doing, as it clearly could never even compile as is.  There are two major issues, one or both of which I suspect to be the cause of the trouble in your actual code:

First, you’re attempting to use `sgelss_` with `double` data.  `sgelss_` operates on `float` (single-precision).  If you have double-precision data, you need to use `dgelss_` instead.

Second, your parameters describe a 5x3 matrix, but remember that LAPACK uses *column-major* ordering for matrix elements.  This means that the matrix as described by your code is:

```
25  1  2 
 5  9  1
 1  3  1
16  1  1
 4  4  1
```

Somehow I doubt that’s the matrix you really want.  More likely you want the matrix:

```
25  5  1
16  4  1
 9  3  1
 4  2  1
 1  1  1
```

I went ahead and put together a working version that assumes this is the matrix you’re actually trying to use:

```
#include <Accelerate/Accelerate.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    double a[] = /* column major storage order! */
    {
        25, 16,  9,  4,  1,
         5,  4,  3,  2,  1,
         1,  1,  1,  1,  1,
    };
    double b[] =
    {
        31,21,13,7,3
    };

    // Setup parameters
    __CLPK_integer m = 5;
    __CLPK_integer n = 3;
    __CLPK_integer nrhs = 1;
    __CLPK_integer lda = 5;
    __CLPK_integer ldb = 5;
    double *s = malloc(3 * sizeof*s);
    double rcond = -1.0f; // use machine precision
    __CLPK_integer rank;
    __CLPK_integer info;
    // Query correct worksize
    double worksize;
    __CLPK_integer lwork = -1;
    dgelss_(&m, &n, &nrhs, a, &lda, b, &ldb, s, &rcond, &rank, &worksize, &lwork, &info);
    // Allocate workspace
    lwork = worksize;
    double *work = malloc(lwork * sizeof *work);
    // Do computation
    dgelss_(&m, &n, &nrhs, a, &lda, b, &ldb, s, &rcond, &rank, work, &lwork, &info);
    // Free workspace
    free(work);
    // Print result vector
    for (int i=0; i<3; ++i)
        printf("%g\t", b[i]);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hey Stephen, thx for the long answer! I actually did't copy my actual source code in here, but changed it to make it a little more readable, in the real one I use __CLPK_real instead of double and __CLPK_integer. On my system __CLPK_real compiles to double. W/e.

Comment: As I pointed out, I also tried rotating the matrix (swapping colums and rows) and actually both results were not what I expected. Can you tell me what the result is in your case (for x inside the b array )

Comment: On current versions of iOS and OSX the code I listed produces [1,1,1,x,x] for the result.

Comment: Huhh, I actually must have had a typo when I defined my matricies. Thanks a lot, when I copy in your's it workd!